# Using tawk.to with Nuxt/Vue Application

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, nuxt.js, tawk.to

Does anyone know how to use tawk.to in a Nuxt application?

I created a file "tawk.js" on my plugin folder with the following code:

```
var Tawk_API = Tawk_API || {},
  Tawk_LoadStart = new Date()
  (function () {
    var s1 = document.createElement('script')
    s0 = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]
    s1.async = true
    s1.src = 'https://embed.tawk.to/[my_ID_HERE]/default'
    s1.charset = 'UTF-8'
    s1.setAttribute('crossorigin', '*')
    s0.parentNode.insertBefore(s1, s0)
  })()
```

And I put it on nuxt.config.js as well:

```
  plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/tawk.js', ssr: false }
  ]
```

It didn't work. It does show some compiled errors:

```
1:1   error  Split initialized 'var' declarations into multiple statements
1:5   error  Identifier 'Tawk_API' is not in camel case
1:16  error  Identifier 'Tawk_API' is not in camel case
1:16  error  'Tawk_API' was used before it was defined
2:3   error  Identifier 'Tawk_LoadStart' is not in camel case
2:3   error  'Tawk_LoadStart' is assigned a value but never used
2:29  error  Unexpected space between function name and paren
3:3   error  Unexpected newline between function and ( of function call
5:5   error  's0' is not defined
10:5   error  's0' is not defined
10:36  error  's0' is not defined
```

Comment: All errors, except the last three, come from your linter settings (I guess eslint?). Read them carefully and you should be able to fix them. The `'s0' is not defined` error suggests, that `document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]` didnt find the `script` tag it was looking for and you might want to use another element (which actually exists) as parent element.

Comment: Thanks Oskar. I could fix the eslint errors with `/* eslint-disable */` but I couldn't figure out how to deal with the 's0' error as the "script" ID might be on their chat widget.

Comment: The `s0` error happens, because your code tries to find an existing `script` tag to use as insertion point for the Tawk script, but it doesnt find one. You can try to append the script to the document body directly like so: Remove `s0 = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]` and replace `s0.parentNode.insertBefore(s1, s0)` with `document.body.appendChild(s1);`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try to use a vue wrapper for tawk. [vue-tawk](https://github.com/papamonkey/vue-tawk)

```
import Tawk from 'vue-tawk'

Vue.use(Tawk, {
    tawkSrc: 'https://embed.tawk.to/5d5528ee2xxxxxxxxxxxx/default'
})
```

Comment: did this work for you ? I tried it in my nuxt website and chat widget is not loading. there is not error in console.

Comment: it worked for me, but is there any way to stop tawk from loading on some routes?

Comment: created() {
    window.Tawk_API.onLoad = function () {
      window.Tawk_API.hideWidget();
    };
  },     Use this to stop tawk from loading on some components

Answer (score 8):

The best way to integrate `tawk.to` in nuxt project is to
go to `nuxt.config.js` and add it as a `script` tag.

```js
// nuxt.config.js
export default {
    // ...
    head: {
        // ...
        script: [
            // ...
            {
                hid: 'tawk.to',
                src:
                    'https://embed.tawk.to/5edf699a9e5f694422903412/default',
                defer: true
            }
        ]
    },
},
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be late, but for future people who wanted to use tawk in Vue/Nuxt. You can use different version for [Vue2/Nuxt2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tawk.to/tawk-messenger-vue-2) and [Vue3/Nuxt3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tawk.to/tawk-messenger-vue-3)